# How does the polarizability of an apolar compound influence properties such as its boiling temperature?

Tags: temperature, boiling-point, polarity

I have understood that the more polar is a compound, the higher is its boiling temperature. But I would like to know what is the justification for this answer.

I am new to chemistry so I would appreciate a simple answer.

Comment: Do you mean perhaps "polarity" rather than polarizability? They are related but not the same.

Answer (score 5):

In non-polar liquids, the intermolecular forces are known as [London dispersion forces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_dispersion_force) (or dipole induced dipole interaction). This is the weakest interaction that exists between molecules.

The **strength of this interaction** depends on **polarisability** of non-polar molecule. As an example, let's take the following examples:

$$
\begin{array}{lr|lr|lr|lr}
\hline
\text{Compound} & \mathrm{bp}/\pu{°C} & \text{Compound} & \mathrm{bp}/\pu{°C} & \text{Compound} & \mathrm{bp}/\pu{°C} & \text{Compound} & \mathrm{bp}/\pu{°C} \\
\hline
\ce{CO2}  & -78.5 & \ce{CCl4} & 76.7  & \ce{CBr4}  & 189.5 & \ce{CI4}   & 329.2 \\
\ce{CS2}  & 46.3  & \ce{CBr4} & 189.5 & \ce{SiCl4} & 57.7  & \ce{SiBr4} & 153.0\\
\ce{CSe2} & 125.5 & \ce{CI4}  & 329.2 &            &       &                 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

In these molecules, polarisability depends on polarisability of anions $(\alpha),$ which depends as

$$\alpha \propto q \times r,$$

where $q$ is the charge and $r$ is the ionic radius.

As charge on each anion is same, hence we can conclude that, *greater the radius, greater is the polarisability, and thus greater is London dispersion forces*.

Therefore, greater boiling point.